# How to convert array to single object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I have array object like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "type1",
        "car": "car1",
        "speed": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "type1",
        "car": "car2",
        "speed": 2
    },
]
```

And i want to convert it single object for prevent data replay.

How can i do this?

```
{
"name": "name1"
"type": "type1",
"car": [
   "car1",
   "car2",
  ],
"speed": [
      1,
      2,
    ],
}
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: `name` and `type` will have same value while `car` and `speed` not?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please add criteria that allows merge and attempt you have made. SO is not **Get Code for Free** site

Comment: Another question closed while writing an answer. I wonder why I come here, and why newcomers even bother to register...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/testo?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `name` and `type` can have same value and `car` and `speed` various,then below is a reference for you

Note: in order to get an expected answer(solution),you need to make you question more clear,the most important thing is **the value of which properties various**

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "type1",
        "car": "car1",
        "speed": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "type1",
        "car": "car2",
        "speed": 2
    },
]

const result = data.reduce((a,v) =>{
  let obj = a.find(i => i.name == v.name)
  if(obj){
   obj.car.push(v.car)
   obj.speed.push(v.speed)
  }else{
   a.push({'name':v.name,'type':v.type,'car':[v.car],'speed':[v.speed]}) 
  }
  return a
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Consider this alternate solution : https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-array-tranformer-s3lznh?file=/src/index.js